# NSOperationQueue with AFNetworking: Call method when NSOperationQueue is completed?

Tags: ios, concurrency, asihttprequest, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am switching my app from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking. In ASIHTTPRequest there is the ASINetworkQueue class, which lets me queue up a series of HTTP requests, and when the queue is completed, call a method. How can I do this with AFNetworking and NSOperationQueue? I can't seem to find out how to add a completion method or block to NSOperationQueue.

Comment: This might work for you: [Get notification when NSOperationQueue finishes all tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049001/get-notification-when-nsoperationqueue-finishes-all-tasks)