# When does the NSOperationQueue remove an operation from the queue?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to know that When does a `NSOperationQueue` remove an operation from the queue? 
I have `NSOperationQueue` which has list of `NSOperation`. At which point the `NSOperationQueue` removes an operation from queue?

1. After starting an operation? OR
2. After Finish/Cancel an operation?

Because I need a notification when all the operations in `NSOPerationqueue` are finished. For this I referred  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049001/get-notification-when-nsoperationqueue-finishes-all-tasks)

Comment: after finish  or cancel

Comment: In operation complete block or fail  check count of operation in operation queue (send notification or use delegate)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Apple Developer Reference

> An operation queue executes its queued NSOperation objects based on
>   their priority and readiness. After being added to an operation queue,
>   an operation remains in its queue until it reports that it is **finished**
>   with its task.

So, `NSOperationQueue` removes an operation after it has been finished.

Source - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Note that if an operation is cancelled, it merely sets the appropriate flags within the operation to mark it as such - The operation itself is responsible for checking if it is cancelled and marking itself finished accordingly. An operation that has not started *should* check if it is cancelled when it starts and return immediately after marking itself finished. An operation which is executing would need to periodically check if it is cancelled and handle that in a similar manner. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1411672-cancel?language=objc

Comment: @Austin remark should be it's own independent answer. This was very important and helpful to note that cancelation does not mean immediate removal from the queue.

Answer (score 6):

`NSOperationQueue` manages its internal queue of `NSOperation`s. An NSOperation will only be removed from the queue after it is canceled or finished.

Note that if an `NSOperation` is cancelled, it merely sets the appropriate flags within the `NSOperation` object to mark it as such - The implementation of the `NSOperation` is responsible for checking if it is cancelled and marking itself finished accordingly. An operation that has not started *should* check if it is cancelled when it starts and return immediately after marking itself finished. A long-running operation which is executing would need to periodically check if it is cancelled and handle that state in a similar manner.

It also makes sense to do this check before executing destructive code or code that will mutate data, such as saving or deleting a managed object from core data.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperation/1411672-cancel?language=objc